# DataTable Rows.IndexOf()

Tags: c#, datatable, rows, indexof, delete-row

I am trying to find a row and then delete that row from a datatable. I keep getting nIndex = -1. Anyone have suggestions?

```
protected void cbxSelected_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)checkbox.NamingContainer;
 string sSampleId = row.Cells[1].Text;

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSampleId))
 {
  DataTable dt;

  if (ViewState["dtTemp"] != null)
  {
   dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtTemp"];
  }
  else
  {
   dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("sample_id");
  }

  DataRow dr;
  string[] drow = new string[] { sSampleId };
  dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr.ItemArray = drow;

  if (checkbox.Checked == true)
  {
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }
  else if (checkbox.Checked == false)
  {
   int nIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
   dt.Rows.RemoveAt(nIndex);
  }

  ViewState.Add("dtTemp", dt);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create a new DataRow

```
dr = dt.NewRow();
```

you won't find it in the DataTable.

You want to remove the row that IS in the DataTable:

```
int nIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

not

```
int nIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
```

**Edit:**
Or maybe not. You'll probably have to loop through the entire DataTable and compare the value in the column:

```
for (var i = dt.Rows.Count; i >= 0; i--)
  if (dt.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == sSampleId) {
    dt.Rows.Remove(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought by building up the datarow that I would be able to find that row in the datatable. I remember doing this in vb, but c# appears to be a little more stingy. I tried your suggestion of looping through the table and deleting the row on a find, this works. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

To find and delete a row in an ADO.NET `DataTable` given its ID:

```
DataRow[] found = dt.Select("sample_id = " + sample_id);
if (found.Length < 0)
{
   found[0].Delete();
}
```

Note that there's a difference between `Delete` and `Remove`.  `Delete` changes the row's state to `RowState.Deleted`, which makes it disappear from the `DataTable` for most purposes.  But it still exists.  This is important if you're using a data adapter to sync the `DataTable` up with an underlying database table:  the adapter will delete the underlying row when you call its `Update` method and only then remove the row from the `Rows` collection.

If you're not using a data adapter, it's OK to use `Remove` to remove a row.